# archlinux cannot boot after replace module init with kmod

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I install archlinux (latest iso from the repository), then I install broadcom-wl
 and connect to the network to run

> pacman -Syu

everything is OK,
then I run

> pacman -Syu

again, it ask that shall I replace module-init with kmod
I type yes, and archlinux says

> rc.conf and profile.d/locale.sh conflicts.

I found the -f option will force replace the configuration 
So I try

> pacman -Syuf

After i reboot 
It shows that

> cannot find device /dev/sda7

then a recovery shell is displayed.

I can never boot archlinux again! I check the menu.list from windows xp, found it OK,

```
# (0) Arch Linux
title  Arch Linux
root   (hd0,6)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda7 ro
initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img

# (1) Arch Linux
title  Arch Linux Fallback
root   (hd0,6)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda7 ro
initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img

# (2) Windows
title Windows
rootnoverify (hd0,0)
makeactive
chainloader +1
```

Comment: `pacman -Syuf`will break your system. You should refer to this news item http://www.archlinux.org/news/initscripts-update-manual-intervention-required/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This truly is a hard one, but I went through it aswell.
Also it is no grub problem!

1. create an arch live stick and boot it
2. mount your root partition to `/mnt` on the live stick
3. mount your /proc partition to `/mnt/proc` using `mount -t procfs proc /mnt/proc`
4. mount your /sys partition to `/mnt/sys` using `mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys`
5. mount your /dev partition to `/mnt/dev` using `mount -t tmpdevfs dev /mnt/dev`
6. mount your /boot partition to `/mnt/boot`
7. chroot into `/mnt` using `chroot /mnt`
8. now perform `pacman -Syu` and watch your kernel being built.
9. finally type `exit` and `reboot`. remove your stick and boot into your now working arch linux

I hope this works for you as well as it did for me :)

Comment: this may work. The only  problem is I  have wireless network connection only, but have no broadcom-wl mod after i upgrade.